# External content via class

Tags: php

I am using the following code succesfully to receive external content from a table class.

```
$url = 'https://www.anything.com';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<table class="main">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</table>" , $first_step[1] );

echo $second_step[0];
```

Now I need the content from a `<a class="link">content</a>`, but

```
$url = 'https://www.anything.com';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( '<a class="link">' , $content );
$second_step = explode("</a>" , $first_step[1] );
```

does not work.

Meanwhile I use this code

```
    // Create DOM from URL or file

    $sFilex = file_get_html("https://www.anything.com", False, $cxContext);

    // Find all links
    foreach($sFilex->find('a[class=link]') as $element)
    echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

to get all `<a class="link">content</a>` links successfully. But how can
I limit this to the first found result only?

The correct code for the is

```
<a class="link" id="55834" href="/this/is/a/test">this is a test</a>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should probably use an HTML/XML parser, like [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/class.domdocument.php), for more reliable results. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641) for more information about parsing HTML in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot! But how can I  limit the results to the first one only?

Comment: I'm currently creating an answer for you, since I figured it could be a bit intimidating for the uninitiated. I'll add an example that answers your comment's question as well.

Comment: Cool! Thanks you very much!

Comment: I've added an answer for you, which I believe it shouldn't have any errors. Let me know if it works for you and/or if you have any more questions about the answer. Also, if you approached it differently, first time around, tell me and I'll try to adjust my answer to your own approach.

Comment: I didn't realize you had started using `simplehtmldom` already. I'm sorry to say that I don't have any experience with that parser. If you still want help with that, I'd recommend starting a new question about it, or perhaps add a tag for [tag:simple-html-dom].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I recommended using a proper HTML parser, which can be a bit intimidating for the uninitiated, I figured I could give you an example, to start of with:

```php
$url = 'https://www.anything.com';

// create a new DOMDocument (an XML/HTML parser)
$doc = new DOMDocument;
// this is used to repair possibly malformed HTML
$doc->recover = true;

// libxml is the parse library that DOMDocument internally uses
// put errors in a memory buffer, in stead of outputting them immediately (basically ignore them, until you need them, if ever)
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

// load the external URL; this might not work if retrieving external files is disabled.
// I will come back on that if it doesn't work for you.
$doc->loadHTMLFile( $url );

// xpath is a query language that allows you to query XML/HTML data structures.
// we create an DOMXPath instance that operates on the earlier created DOMDocument
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );

// this is a query to get all <table class="main">
// note though, that it will also match <table class="test maintain">, etc.
// which might not be what you need
$tableMainQuery = '//table[contains(@class,"main")]';
/* explanation:
   //         match any descendant of the current context, in this case root
   table      match <table> elements
   []         with the predicate(s)
   contains() match a string, that contains some string, in this case:
   @class     the attribute 'class'
   'main'     containing the string main
*/   

// execute the query
// $nodes will be an instance of DOMNodeList (containing DOMNode instances)
$nodes = $xpath->query( $tableMainQuery );

// loop through all nodes
foreach( $nodes as $node ) {
  // echo the inner HTML content of the found node (or do something else with it)
  // the getInnerHTML() helper function is defined below)
  // remove htmlentities to get the actual HTML
  echo htmlentities( getInnerHTML( $node ) );
}

// this is a query to get all <a class="link">
// similar comments and explanation apply as with previous query
$aLinkQuery = '//a[contains(@class,"link")]';

// execute the query
// $nodes will be an instance of DOMNodeList (containing DOMNode instances)
$nodes = $xpath->query( $aLinkQuery );

// loop through all nodes
foreach( $nodes as $node ) {
  // do something with the found nodes again
}

// clear any errors still left in memory
libxml_clear_errors();
// set previous state
libxml_use_internal_errors( $useInternalErrors );

// the helper function to get the inner HTML of a found node
function getInnerHTML( DOMNode $node ) {
  $html = '';
  foreach( $node->childNodes as $childNode ) {
    $html .= $childNode->ownerDocument->saveHTML( $childNode );
  }

  return $html;
}
```

Now, to get only the first found node of an xpath query (a `DOMNodeList` instance), I think the simplest would be:

```php
// in both the examples below $node will contain the element you are looking for
// $nodes will keep being a list of all found nodes

if( $nodes->length > 0 ) {
  $node = $nodes->item( 0 );
  // do something with the $node
}

// or, perhaps
if( null !== ( $node = $nodes->item( 0 ) ) ) {
  // do something with the $node
}
```

You could also adjust the xpath query to only find the first matching node, but I believe it would then still return a `DOMNodeList`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for your help and time! It gets everything within the `<a class="link">content</a>`, but using the `if( $nodes->len...` code  lists all results as before. And: any chance to get the pure html from that `<a class="link">content</a>` (including id, style, href,etc...)?

Comment: You're welcome @vloryan! I edited my answer in the meantime, which you may have missed. Let me know if it answered your "get pure HTML" question. If you want the complete HTML of a `$node` (the outer HTML, not just the inner HTML), you can simply do: `$node->ownerDocument->saveHTML( $node )`;

Comment: And about the `if( $nodes->len...`: make sure you are not looping through the `$nodes` with `foreach()`, i.e.: replace the `foreach()` loops with the `if( $nodes->len...` examples.

Comment: Nice, nice, thanks! But I still got all, not only the first result. I have tried to replace the `// loop through all nodes...` lines with your alternate `if( $nodes->length > 0 ) { $node = $nodes->item( 0 );}`, but there were no results at all. Sorry to bother you!

Comment: Are you sure `$nodes->length` is larger than `0`, for the relevant query? If it is `0` then `foreach(...` shouldn't work either. Try to do a `var_dump( $nodes->length )` to see what you get. Are you not mixing up the two separate queries here (the `<table>` one and the `<a>` one)?

Comment: Ok, I got two problems left. The result for the `a class` does not show up in pure html though i use `echo htmlentities( getInnerHTML( $node ) );` And when I replace the foreach with the other code I still get no result at all (https://codeshare.io/5vKmQl). `var_dump( $nodes->length )` gives me `5` results.

Comment: @vloryan 1. remove the surrounding `htmlentities()` if you need the original HTML, `htmlentities()` simply allows you to view HTML in a browser as text. 2. You need to use the `$node` after `$node = $nodes->item( 0 );`. In other words: `$nodes` will keep containing **all** nodes found, `$node` will contain the **first** node found.

Comment: Any chance to have a more precise alternative for `'//a[contains(@class,"link")]';`? Guess I have fetched other classes containg **link** :)

Comment: @vloryan That depends on how precise you can define it. :-) What's the most precise properties you can find about the link you want? (Without the actual `href` of course, because then there's no need to code it :-))

Comment: I got '//a[contains(@class,"games_tools")]' which also fetches `<a class="play_tools">'. Exact match for 'games_tools' would be nice!

Comment: @vloryan Hmmm, that should not happen, unless the `play_tools` one also has a class named `games_tools`. In which case it's gonna get tricky. Than you'd need to find a property that uniquely identifies the link you need.

Comment: Any chance to define exact matches?

Comment: @vloryan Yes, that would be `//a[@class="games_tools"]`, but as soon as another class is added to that link, you are in trouble. Could you edit your question and give a small sample of the actual HTML code you are parsing?

Comment: My fault, play_tools was placed somewhere else, that's why i have a wrong result. any chance to define the `//a[contains(@class,"tooltip")]`; after this text (only occurs once per page): `Search results: Clubs`?

Comment: @vloryan Sorry, I was/am a bit tied up at the moment, but I saw you already asked a new question. I was going to suggest that as well. :-) Glad you found a solution!

Comment: Hi, me again. Using this in a `php for each`loop results in this error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getInnerHTML() (previously declared in...` **after the first loop** (which works fine). Can you help me solving this? Would be great! Thanks.

Comment: @vloryan Yes, it's very simple: you cannot redefine a function in PHP, so you must put the definition of the function somewhere where you are sure it will only be defined once. So: outside the `foreach()` loop (perhaps at the top of your file, for instance).